# Compute the ratio between the number of rows where A=True, to the number of rows where A=False

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, count, python-polars

I have a Polars dataframe:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "nrs": [1, 2, 3, None, 5],
        "names": ["foo", "ham", "spam", "egg", None],
        "random": np.random.rand(5),
        "A": [True, True, False, False, False],
    }
)
```

How can I compute the ratio between the number of rows where `A==True`, to the number of rows where `A==False`? Note that `A` is always `True` or `False`. I found a solution, but it seems a bit clunky:

```
ntrue = df.filter(pl.col('A')==1).shape[0]
ratio = ntrue/(df.shape[0]-ntrue)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage polars' expression API as follow.

```py
df.select(pl.col("A").sum() / pl.col("A").not_().sum()).item()
```

The summing works as *A* is a boolean column. If this is not the case, you can exchange `pl.col("A")` for another corresponding boolean expression.

Comment: Very nice. Suppose instead I need to compute the ratio A==True to the total number of rows. Would this work? `df.select(pl.col("A").sum() / pl.len()).item()`

Comment: @DeltaIV In this case, you could even simplify the expression to `df.select(pl.col("A").mean()).item()`.

Answer (score 2):

Since we know that we can sum boolean values. True will be `1` and False will be `0`.

All the True values will be:

```
t = df['A'].sum()
```

All the False values will be:

```
f = (~df['A']).sum()   # negating True values
```

Ratio `True` is to `False` will be:

```
ratio = t/f
#0.6666666666666666
```

If you want `True` is to all the values in the column then:

```
ratio_true_all_rows = t/len(df)
#0.4
```

If you want `False` is to all the values in the column then:

```
ratio_true_all_rows = f/len(df)
#0.4
```

---

There is one more thing, if you do not have Boolean data you can use `value_counts()`.

**It will give the frequency of each value in the column**

```
df['A'].value_counts()

A      count
bool    u32
false   3
true    2
```

---

If you want to use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.unique(df['A'], return_counts=True)

#(array([False,  True]), array([3, 2], dtype=int64))
```